# Django: how to use MultipleChoiceField in a form/admin

Tags: python, django

I need a MultipleChoiceField for and online enrollment application. When I try to use them in a field I get the an unknown field error. They also do not appear in the admin panel.

```
# models.py
...
CHILDCARE_REASONS = (('Working', 'working'),('Training', 'training'),('Teen Parent', 'teen_parent'),('Working W/Child With A Disability', 'child_disability'),('Adult W/Disability', 'adult_disability'),)
reasons_for_childcare = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHILDCARE_REASONS)
...

# forms.py
class EnrollForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = EnrollmentApplication
    fields = [
        ...
        'reasons_for_childcare ',
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use a form field in your model, it isn't right. For a multiple choice field I recommend the [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/) instead.
2. You will need to change the tuple order, the correct way is the key first, then the value.
3. There is an extra space in the end of your field string "reasons_for_childcare".

So, with that in mind, the solution would look like this:

**models.py**

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class EnrollmentApplication(models.Model):
    CHILDCARE_REASONS = (('working', 'Working'),
                         ('training', 'Training'),
                         ('teen_parent', 'Teen Parent'),
                         ('child_disability', 'Working W/Child With A Disability'),
                         ('adult_disability', 'Adult W/Disability'))
    reasons_for_childcare = MultiSelectField(choices=CHILDCARE_REASONS)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EnrollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnrollmentApplication
        fields = [
            'reasons_for_childcare',
        ]
```

Comment: django-multiselectfield doesn't seem to work with Django 2.1.  The example is not working anyway.